# Do I need a bootable USB drive to install Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

And if you do, how much space should I partition for it? Can I just install it to my laptop? I have so many questions! I'm a newbie to Linux :D

By the way, I'm running Windows 8 on a Lenovo IdeaPad.

Comment: answers for all these questions are found on this site,please search before posting a question.

Comment: Please see [Install Ubuntu 13.10](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest).

Answer (score 0):

To install Ubuntu you'll need either -

- USB key with 1GB of free space + Unetbootin to copy the CD to USB and make it bootable
- A burned DVD of the Ubuntu ISO (CD is no longer supported, because of 950MB image size)
- To mount the Ubuntu.iso in Windows8 and launch "Wubi", Windows Ubuntu installer.

You'll need at least a 6GB partition, but that's really shrunk. I personally wouldn't go under 25GB.

You can "just" install it to your laptop.